# Django 3 Python 3.8 whitenoise not serving request.user

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, whitenoise

I get the error

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

When writing:

```
x.user = request.user
x.save()
```

In Django, I updated whitenoise to the latest version and I'm pretty sure that a post request would have the user attached. How do I return the request.user from the post request in Django?

Some of my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contacts',
    'pytz',
    'registration',
    'crispy_forms',
    'storages',
    'el_pagination',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Comment: Can you share your settings.py?

Comment: see above edited.

Answer (score 0):

Following the whitenoise docs :
`Edit your settings.py file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware`

For example:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that, however the probelm is more likely to do with this use of request.user... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests  I have session middleware enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` into the middleware to get the method from HttpRequest.user https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```